# redirect_to in controller only routes to absolute url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a little check in my controller after login in my home_controller.

```
before_filter :authorize_admin, only: :index
    def authorize_admin
        redirect_to '/admin/index' if current_user.admin?
        #redirects to admin controller if admin? true 
      end
```

Annoying thing is it only works when I put in the absolute path. I tried `redirect_to 'admin_index'` and `redirect_to 'admin#index'`. But both ends in an error.

This is the log from the server:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000admin_index
```

And for the controller#action way its

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000admin#index
```

Its obvious what happens, but its kinda annoying to do the redirect by absolute url.

Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: HTTP protocol states that URL for redirection must be absolute. What error do you get?

Comment: Try `redirect_to admins_path if current_user.admin?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
redirect_to {:controller => 'admin', :action => 'index'} if current_user.admin?
```

Or easier, if you have defined a [named route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)

```
redirect_to admin_index_path if current_user.admin?
```

Comment: This should solve your problem. You could also use "admins_url"

Comment: funny thing is `redirect_to admin_index_path if current_user.admin?` worked. And the first one doesnt work...

Comment: ` admin_index GET  |  /admin/index(.:format)    |     admin#index
` ist my rake route